# NodeJs integration with Springboot

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, rest, backend

How can I make a Rest call from Nodejs backend to the Spring-boot microservice? I have tried doing some research but couldn't find out the best one.
Thank you

Comment: What do you need to do? both backend? I think you need create a spring boot that expose an REST API and create a project in node that consume a REST API. is your question about the best lib in node? could explain more about it?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reaching out. yes both are backend and i have the endpoints ready in springboot and need to be consumed by nodejs . Also , there is one module in nodejs where i need to include the rest call? How do i include the rest call in custom module?

Comment: I think you should improve your question post for better helping. I found this article on first link on google https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/http-requests-in-node-js.html , may  could help you to improve your question and what have you tried

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any library like Axios, node-fetch others to make HTTP request to you spring boot server.
You can also take help from [here](https://nodejs.dev/learn/making-http-requests-with-nodejs)